# How to check each row (timestamp - 60 seconds) to determine if there are duplicates data or not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, duplicates

I have table like this

[image: table data will be like this]

You will see red cross signed is the result that I want.
I want to move red cross signed to error logs table because it indicates duplicate data.

To determine data is duplicate:

1. find data 60s before each row timestamps
2. same advertiser_id, offer_id, commission_id, commission_tier_id, creative_id, publisher_id, publisher_asset_id, source_id

Example:

```
1545981655
1545981657 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981657 - 60 = 1545981597. Search first data > 1545981597 except this line. 1545981655 will return.
1545981660 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981660 - 60 = 1545981600. Search first data > 1545981600 except this line. 1545981655 will return.
1545981662 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981662 - 60 = 1545981602. Search first data > 1545981602 except this line. 1545981655 will return.
1545981707  -> won't marked as duplicate because 1545981707 - 60 = 1545981647. Search first data > 1545981647 except this line. 1545981655 won't return because publisher_asset_id is different.
1545981710 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981710 - 60 = 1545981650. Search first data > 1545981650 except this line. 1545981707 will return.
1545981712 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981712 - 60 = 1545981652. Search first data > 1545981650 except this line. 1545981707 will return.
1545981714 x -> will marked as duplicate because 1545981714 - 60 = 1545981654. Search first data > 1545981654 except this line. 1545981707 will return.
1545981718  -> won't marked as duplicate because 1545981718 - 60 = 1545981658. Search first data > 1545981658 except this line. No data returns, because pubisher_asset_id is different
```

How to achieve this in mysql query statement instead of loop through whole data?

Result that I want to achieve like this :

[image: result table want to achieve]

Need you guys help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems there are more conditions than just 60 seconds between timestamps, otherwise 1545981707  should be a duplicate. Please edit your question to include that information, preferably along with table structures and some sample data for your expected output. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: thank you nick for your comment.
I add another condition beside timestamp and also result table I want to achieve

Comment: @TeddyHendryanto Which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Hi @isuru89.. I use v5.7.21 for mysql

Answer (score 1):

Rename table T to your table and try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, advertiser_id, offer_id, commission_id, commission_tier_id, creative_id, publisher_id, publisher_asset_id, source_id, impression_timestamp,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY advertiser_id, offer_id, commission_id, commission_tier_id, creative_id, publisher_id, publisher_asset_id, source_id ORDER BY impression_timestamp RANGE 60 PRECEDING) AS DuplicateFlag
FROM T
) DetectDuplicate
WHERE DuplicateFlag > 1
```

**EDIT**: Before MySQL 8, the query above could not be done and must be replaced by a query with JOIN (unfortunately a bit slower):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.*
FROM T T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T T2
  ON T1.id                   <> T2.id
 AND T1.advertiser_id         = T2.advertiser_id
 AND T1.offer_id              = T2.offer_id
 AND T1.commission_id         = T2.commission_id
 AND T1.commission_tier_id    = T2.commission_tier_id
 AND T1.creative_id           = T2.creative_id
 AND T1.publisher_id          = T2.publisher_id
 AND T1.publisher_asset_id    = T2.publisher_asset_id
 AND T1.source_id             = T2.source_id
 AND T1.impression_timestamp >= T2.impression_timestamp - 60
WHERE T2.id IS NOT NULL
```

At least one other syntax is possible such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM T Main
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T
   WHERE id                   <> Main.id
     AND advertiser_id         = Main.advertiser_id
     AND offer_id              = Main.offer_id
     AND commission_id         = Main.commission_id
     AND commission_tier_id    = Main.commission_tier_id
     AND creative_id           = Main.creative_id
     AND publisher_id          = Main.publisher_id
     AND publisher_asset_id    = Main.publisher_asset_id
     AND source_id             = Main.source_id
     AND impression_timestamp >= Main.impression_timestamp - 60
)
```

Comment: Hi @lau..
thank you for your help.
I have problem in OVER syntax.
I think there is no OVER clause in MySQL.
Am I right?

Comment: Actually, there is (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) but it must be new from version 8.